# Conversão de caractere para binário

Tags: python-3.x

Estou desenvolvendo uma pequena aplicação em 'python' que necessita da conversão de caracteres para binário. No entanto, quero saber se existe uma função específica para este tipo de tarefa.

Answer (score 0):

Cheguei a uma solução para este caso de conversão. Neste caso, criei duas funções com estruturas de repetição para iterar cada caractere. A primeira converte de binário para string, já a segunda, de string para binário:

```
def bin_to_str(binario):
    binario = str(binario)
    caractere = ''
    string = ''
    tamanho = len(binario)
    k = 1
    for j in binario:
        if j != ' ':
            caractere += j
            if k == tamanho:
                string += chr(int(caractere, 2))
        else:
            string += chr(int(caractere, 2))
            caractere = ''  # 0x101100110
        k += 1
    return string


def str_to_bin(string):
    binario = ''
    for i in string:
        binario += bin(ord(i))[2::] + ' '
    return binario

text = str(input("Entre com um texto: "))
binary = str_to_bin(text)
print(binary)


binary = str(input("Entre com um binario: "))
text = bin_to_str(binary)
print(text)
input()
```